# Remove container in block class

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, containers

I want to remove some items from a page when certain conditions apply. I got a solution but I'm wondering if there isn't any better way to do this.

Now the code that I have is for each block that I want to remove:

```
 protected function _toHtml() {
    if ($condition) {
      return '';
    }

    return parent::_toHtml();
 }
```

Now I was wondering if ther is a way to remove a container from the layout file instead of doing this for every block inside a single container. I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
protected function _toHtml() {
    if ($condition) {
      $this->getLayout()->removeOutputElement('container.name.in.layout');
      return '';
    }

    return parent::_toHtml();
  }
```

Anyone know's how to remove containers form the layout page within a block class, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **You can try something like this,**

```
$myXml = '<referenceContainer name="container.name.in.layout" remove="true"/>';
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate($myXml);
$layout->generateXml();
```

> **Or you can call an observer class on `layout_generate_blocks_before` event and add below code in observer**

```
    $layout = $observer->getLayout();
    $block = $layout->getBlock('container.name.in.layout');

    if ($block) {
        //you can apply or add you condition here.
        $layout->unsetElement('container.name.in.layout');
    }
```

First code also work in Observer just need to change this line **`$layout = $this->getLayout();`** to **`$layout = $observer->getLayout();`**